# Bootstrap Tooltip in ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, ember.js

I have no problem when I use Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip in a simple html file. But when I try to do the same in my Ember application something goes wrong. I try to reproduce my code snippet here:

```
// Link in template
<a id="xyz" rel="tooltip" title="My tooltip">LINK</a>

// Ember View fragment
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$("a#xyz).tooltip();
    this.$("a#xyz).click(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Tooltip changed').tooltip('fixTitle');
    });        
}
```

First, the style of the tooltip is not the same as the one in the single HTML page (black background and white small font). It is a bigger tooltip with big font size appearing on the right.

Second, I am unable to change the tooltip text clicking on the link as I try to do in the click event. It thows an error saying "no such method 'fixTitle' for tooltip widget instance". But that code runs perfectly in my single HTML file without Ember.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: it'll be helpful if u can post a fiddle...

Answer (score 4):

Finally solved my issue. It was a conflict between libraries. I use Bootstrap but I also had Jquery UI. Both libraries have a tooltip component. I started with JQuery UI to have an autocomplete component. I have already discarded it and replaced with Bootstrap Typeahead.